# Zsh - Modify File Completion w/ Quotes

Tags: zsh, quoting, autocomplete

I've been using Zsh recently, and when I complete a file name within quotes, the completion adds a space after the completed file name.  Interestingly, this does not occur when I complete directory names in quotes.

To illustrate (using an underscore to signify the cursor location):

```
$ mv ".xmod_"  --<TAB>--> $ mv ".Xmodmap _"
```

Preferably, I would like to have the following happen:

```
$ mv ".xmod_" --<TAB>--> $ mv ".Xmodmap" _
```

This seems like the most intuitive way to me, anyway. I just want to remove the space added between the completed file name and the ending quotation mark.

I did try searching for a solution to this, but I'm afraid my minimal knowledge of Zsh and the possible causes of this have not led me to a solution so far.

---

**Update:** Originally, I had this question as just relevant to the "mv" program, but I noticed that this behavior with the quotes seems to occur with all file completions (I only tried "cp" in addition).

Also, here is the modules section of my *.zshrc*, in case any might be causing this to happen:

```
autoload -U colors compinit promptinit select-word-style zkbd
compinit
promptinit
colors
select-word-style bash
```

Apart from this, and some other minor option settings, there isn't much else in my *.zshrc*.

Comment: Which version of zsh are you using? The intended behaviour seems to be the default in 5.0.5. Can you try if the behaviour persists if you start zsh with `zsh -f`? If it does I would assume a bug in your zsh, as I cannot thing of any use for this behaviour, else the problem resides in your configuration.

Comment: I'm using Zsh 5.0.5, and when I tried using `zsh -f` like you mentioned, the problem still occurs.